# Redirect an IP Address with .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I use LiteSpeed and I’m wondering what code I need to add to my .htaccess file to redirect certain IP addresses to another link/website. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like the following :

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^1\.2\.3\.4\.5$
RewriteRule ^ https://example.com [L,R]
```

This redirects the client with ip address `1.2.3.4.5`  to `example.com`.

Comment: Thanks. I just found this in my .htaccess file. Any ideas what it is?

```RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]```

Comment: @Ryder Cragie This rule removes trailing slashes from your URLs. Ie : changes `/foobar/` to `/foobar`

Comment: Ah okay. Well it doesn't work so I'll remove it. Thanks.